# General Knowledge Question: Network Access Time, Cache Access Time, Disk Access Time

Tags: java, networking, distributed-caching, distributed-system

I have written a simulator of a client-server based distributed file system. Now to calculate the average block access time,  I want the following:

1. Local Cache Access Time
2. Client to Client Cache Access Time (same network)
3. Client to Server Cache Access Time (different Network)
4. Client to Disk Access Time

Assuming if the block size is 64MB...

Could any one give me approximate times...
Links to prove it would be appreciated...

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "local cache" access time?  Do you mean from main memory?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "same network" vs "different network"?

Comment: Yes, local cache = main memory...And same network vs different network... Server is kind of repository far away...and clients are group of nodes in one network using it... Assume, Google's file system... so their server and the clients are computers in one organization...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply measure it?

For network, use the [ping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping) command to measure latency, and divide 64MB by available bandwith for propagation delay. For files use [cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29), for main memory, use

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] data = new byte[64*1024*1024];
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    int sum = 0;
    for (byte b : data) {
        sum += b;
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(end - start).movePointLeft(9));
}
```

Which on my machine yields

> 0.209555405

Comment: I am not implementing the real system, it is simulation, so I can get the local access time as you mentioned but how about the other times?